# Custom post type URL structure with site.com/custom_taxonomy_slug/post_name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, archives, slug

I'm quite new to wordpress and I'm struggling to adjust the URL structure to my needs.
I work with a theme that provides a plugin for a custom portfolio post type along with custom taxonomies : portfolio_category and portfolio_tag.

I'd like to use this post type to display two types of items : products and projects so I thought I'd create two portfolio_categories (one for projects and one for products).

I'd like the URL structure to work as follows :
- site.com/products to reach the archive page corresponding to products
- site.com/products/product_name to reach the product page
- same for projects

So the rule would be site.com/%portfolio_category%/%postname%
It means removing all indication of post types so I'm not sure it's easy...

Is this the right way ? Or should I make two separate post types ?

In any way, how should I setup the permalinks to work this way ?

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 separate post types.  It will save confusion now, and provide flexibility later if you decide to do more with each of the posts.  There will be a bit more work, but the payout will be worth it.

When you're setting up the CPTs, they will automatically have archive pages and the individual posts can be set behind the post type slug.